# Python: Find screen resolution

Tags: python, screen-resolution

I'm trying to find the screen resolution/size of the user for a simple game I'm writing in python, and save that in some form to a variable. I need to do this in python only, but I don't mind using external modules that aren't built in as long as they are in the standard library already, so I don't want to download anything. How can I do this?